# Yii2 Basic- How to display data table in looping using model?

Tags: php, foreach, yii2

I'm trying to display a loop of data (in table form) for child data to be display in parent view. Below is the code for the table view:

//display child data loop

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header">
            <h3 class="box-title">Details</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">Code</th>
                            <th>Part Number</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Size</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    foreach($modelsMaintenanceItem as $i => $modelMaintenanceItem)
                    {
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $modelMaintenanceItem->Code; ?></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $modelMaintenanceItem->Part_Number; ?></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $modelMaintenanceItem->Quantity; ?></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $modelMaintenanceItem->Size; ?></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $modelMaintenanceItem->Description; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside controller for function actionView, the code are as below:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $searchModel = new MaintenanceSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    // $model = new Maintenance();
    $modelsMaintenanceItem = [new MaintenanceItem]; //pass model to be use in view page

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'modelsMaintenanceItem' => $this->findModel($id),
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        // 'modelsMaintenanceItem' => (empty($modelsMaintenanceItem)) ? [new MaintenanceItem] : $modelsMaintenanceItem //pass model to be use in view page
    ]);
}
```

Help me please... I'm Stuck here. I think I need to do some changes in controller for function actionView, about 'modelsMaintenanceItem' but I'm not sure what should I put there.

Comment: Use `GridView` to display set of models.

Answer (score 1):

If you want really accessing to dataProvider models  you should use
`$models = $dataProvider->getModels();`
and for html code inside a foreach,  suggest  also   the echo of the html code or use the alternative syntax for control structures eg: `<?php foreach(...) : ?> ... <?php endforeach; ?>` syntax
eg:

```
   <?php
        $models = $dataProvider->getModels(); 
        foreach($models as $i => $modelMaintenanceItem):
  ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $modelMaintenanceItem->Code; ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $modelMaintenanceItem->Part_Number; ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $modelMaintenanceItem->Quantity; ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $modelMaintenanceItem->Size; ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $modelMaintenanceItem->Description; ?></td>
        </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

anyway the simplest  way for show a table in Yii2 is based on gridview

```
<?php  
 use yii\grid\GridView;

?>

...

<?php  

  echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'Code',
            'Part_Number',
            'Quantity',
            'Size',                
            'Description',    
        ],
]); ?>
```